# Problems with PDO parameters binding

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm building a CRUD with pure PHP+PDO Mysql driver.

I've got a page that lists the data contained in a DB table and I want to implements some filters, but I'm stuck on binding paramenters to PDO with a dynamic query.

For example this code works well with and without the `$_GET["op"]`.

```
$params = [];
$pag_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cells WHERE 1 ";

if(!empty($_GET["op"])){
    $pag_query .= "AND op=:op ";
    $params["op"] = $_GET["op"];
}

$stmt = db()->prepare($pag_query);
$stmt->execute($params);

$n_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

But I cannot make this query work.

```
<?php

//some logic here to get $limit and $offset

$params["limit"] = $limit;
$params["offset"] = $offset;
$tbl_query = "SELECT * FROM cells WHERE 1 ";

if(!empty($_GET["op"])){
    $tbl_query .= "AND op=:op ";
    $params["op"] = $_GET["op"];
}

$tbl_query .= "ORDER BY cid LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset";

//Prepare the query
$stmt = db()->prepare($tbl_query);
$stmt->execute($params);

$table = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

It gives me this error message.

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''20' OFFSET '0'' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\celldb\manage.php on line 64

If I simulate the query on PhpMyadmin it works well and it works also if I remove `if(!empty($_GET["op"])` case and pass `$limit` and `$offset` using `$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: `$pag_query` != `$tbl_query`

Comment: I wrote wrong here but in my code was right :P

Comment: amazing ... retyping code instead of copy and pasting :)

Comment: No, it's because i edited something, like some comments

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely at the error message, it gives you the answer:

> near ''20' OFFSET '0''

The parameters are both strings, where integers are expected. And as the [documentation for PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-parameters) explains:

> All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.

That is why you must explicitly define them as integers with:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: var_dump of both variables: `int(20) int(0)`, this is not the problem

Comment: @ClaudioKing My bad, I updated the answer. You need to explicitly define integers as such in cases like this.

Comment: How to do this if i have 5/6 clauses like `if(!empty($_GET["op"]))` with mixed types parameters (int, string and floats) ?

Comment: @ClaudioKing MySQL is pretty forgiving in WHERE conditions (like you can check an integer column with `WHERE id='12'` and it'll work), but the LIMIT/OFFSET are not so forgiving. They always require integers.

Comment: @ClaudioKing check the variable type and assign it the type.  Something like `is_int($param) ? PDO::PARAM_INT : PDO::PARAM_STR`

Comment: Thank you, I will make a loop that does that